# How can I name the output of a line of java code in a batch file dynamically

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to use a simple batch file to perform some scripting to run a java program in a loop,

```
for %%f IN (*.txt) DO (
    java abc %%f > %%f + "[parsed].txt"
)
```

The program reads all the text files in the current directory and runs a java program. I want to store the output of each of these files into a new text file with `[parsed]` being appended to the name.
Example: if the input text file is `test.txt` then the output should be stored in `test[parsed].txt`.
The code that is written above has a syntax error and I am not being able to work around it using variables.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error?
And you rather need something like this:

```
for %%f IN (*.txt) DO (
    java abc "%%f" >"%%~nf[parsed].txt"
)
```

In batch there's no need of `+` for concatenation.

Comment: Thanks! One issue I face is that the file's name is outputted as `test.txt[parsed]`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you mean the result file - yes.With `%%~nf` you can get only the file name.I'l edit my answer. With `for /?` you can get more info about gettable file attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%f IN (*.txt) DO (
    java abc "%%f" > "%%~nf[parsed]%%~xf"
)
```